# É possível aproveitar a mesma view WPF para Desktop e Web?

Tags: c#, .net, aplicação-web, visual-studio, wpf

Caros, nunca programei com WPF mas em breve terei a oportunidade e já pensando no futuro, que é agora, em que aplicações desktop estarão/estão sendo migradas para a web e, também pensando nos que ainda relutam contra isso, que nos caso são os clientes, eu quero fazer o sistema servir tanto pela web como que por desktop.

Tentando evitar redundância de código eu lhes pergunto: É possível usar a mesma *view* para desktop e para a web? Se não, até onde eu posso ir sem ter redundâncias de códigos desnecessárias, ou realmente a *view* para desktop é diferente para a *view* web?

Gostaria de aproveitar a oportunidade para perguntar se o WPF roda, pelo menos, nos browsers mais populares, como IE, Firefox e Chrome? Também se é multiplataforma, para Linux e Mac OS?

Comment: Resumindo, para a primeira pergunta, a resposta é não.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Mas saberia me responder sobre as outras questões também?

Comment: @user3628, acredito que seja mais interresante ter uma arquitetura multicamada, então você poderá ter quantas camadas de apresentação quiser (desktop, web, mobile, wearable, tvs, geladeiras, etc) e manter as suas regras de negocio centralizadas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como não era resposta, preferi mandar pelos comentários, mas aqui vai:

Ainda não ouvi reclamações do WPF em nenhum navegador. Se você utilizar Silverlight então, vai, com certeza ter a tranquilidade da compatibilidade cross-browser de forma nativa.

Quanto à migrar, isso acaba se tornando pessoal demais, eu, pelo menos, acho mais interessante iniciar novos projetos no WPF do que migrar, ou, se for migrar, como você disse que não tem experiência em wpf, sugiro projetos pequenos para não se deparar com um *monstro* de primeira. Mas tem gente que prefere grandes desafios logo de cara, então, como eu falei, é bem relativo.

Finalmente, já que você ainda está aprendendo, acho válido dar uma olhada [neste exemplo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25795/Creating-the-Same-Program-in-Windows-Forms-and-WPF) que mostra o mesmo sistema em windows forms e wpf.

Comment: Perdoe minha ignorância, mas `Se você utilizar Silverlight então, vai, com certeza ter a tranquilidade da compatibilidade cross-browser de forma nativa.` para Linux e Mac OS, é isso mesmo?

Comment: E também.. WPF com Silverlight? Tenho muita coisa para pesquisar ainda.. (rs)

Comment: Exatamente isso. Bastante pesquisa, mas adianto que vale a pena.

Comment: Pra terminar de te convencer sobre o WPF. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/602a3c75-d996-4a39-8c77-0439bde0034e/wpf-x-winforms

Answer (score 3):

Não existe WPF para web e nunca existirá. Web é web, se não estiver usando HTML, CSS, JavaScript, não é web. Nem mesmo Silverlight é web, assim como Flash. O fato de rodar em cima de um navegador não significa que é web.

Se quer rodar WPF em um navegador se prepare para usar só o Internet Explorer, obviamente só no Windows. Até onde eu sei, nem mesmo o Microsoft Edge que substituiu o IE pode rodar WPF (que no fim virou Chromium). E não é qualquer Windows que vai rodar, precisa ter um .NET instalado e atualizado. Ou seja, esqueça isto.

Quer fazer algo para desktop, faça com WPF, Windows Forms ou WinRT. Não caia no marketing. Se vai fazer algo para web use as tecnologias padrões citadas acima. Não adianta tentar aproveitar que não dá.

E aplicações desktop não estão sendo migradas para web, a não ser que a pessoa goste de modismos. Existem novas aplicações ou pelo menos novos clientes web para aplicações quando elas são pertinentes e necessárias.

Com o [fim do .NET Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101) algumas coisas aí podem ter mudado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).