# O .NET Framework está morto?

Tags: .net, .net-core

Em uma pequena discussão com Maniero, [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/385513/24529), ele disse a respeito sobre a infraestrutura do .NET Framework:

> Alias vamos começar falar do .NET ou até da BCL **porque o .NET Framework morreu**.

Por que o .NET Framework está morto (ou morrendo)? Isso diz que toda a família .NET está morta também?

Comment: Creio que não. O que está havendo (acredito eu), estão migrando para o .net Core (isso é um bom sinal).

Comment: Primeiro, é bom notar que ".net" é um termo abrangente que contempla muitas coisas (linguagens, VMs, frameworks, APIs...). Dito isso, saiba que o _.net framework_ não vai mais receber funcionalidades. Isso não significa que ele está _morto_, mas sim que ele está _finalizado_. Ao contrário de coisas como o Silverlight, o .net framework não é uma aberração e você não precisa fugir dele.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Obviamente que o comentário foi um pouco informal e meio *click bait* :). Mas sim, ele está morto em certo sentido. Não em todos.

O .NET Framework é uma das implementações do [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) e de outras coisas necessárias pra tudo funcionar, como por exemplo a [BCL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194677/101). Como foi a primeira e meio que oficial por ser mantida pela Microsoft, e vir com o Windows e ser a única que muitos conhecem ela virou [sinônimo de .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184716/101). Mas o nome oficial dele é .NET Framework.

Tiveram algumas implementações que não foram muito pra frente e a que mais deu certo é o Mono. Este *framework* substitui "integralmente" o .NET Framework. As pessoas muitas vezes não se dão conta do seu papel. O Mono é a base para o Xamarin e o Unity funcionar.

Mais tarde a Microsoft percebeu que aquele modelo de *framework* tinha alguns problemas e de certa forma o modelo do Mono era um pouco melhor, lembrando que ambos, mesmo tendo filosofias ligeiramente diferentes, atendiam a todos requisitos para rodar o CLR, tinha a BCL e obviamente atendia a necessidade de sua principal linguagem, o C#. Então ela precisava de um produto que não fosse tão ligado ao .NET Framework, precisava ser uma coisa nova, melhor, com filosofia diferente, então nasceu o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101).

Claro que ele foi baseado inicialmente no .NET Framework para não perder todo o trabalho. Não vou falar muito dele porque já tem [outras perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225927/101) sobre o tema, mas pra mim foi uma revolução, mudou tudo, era o que precisava pra ficar um ambiente muito bom. E ele é 100% código e projeto aberto, e com ajuda da comunidade ele prosperou como nenhum outro produto da Microsoft. Algumas pessoas torceram o nariz no começo mas eu vi que ele era a solução correta para maioria dos problemas que tínhamos com o .NET Framework (que não vou falar aqui porque o foco é outro). Pra saber mais tem algumas perguntas sobre o assunto:

- [Como o C# é executado em outras plataformas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/315868/101)
- [Quais as diferenças dos ".NET"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/275588/101)
- [O que devo entender quando dizem ".NET"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184716/101)
- [Qual é o jeito correto de chamar as versões do C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101)

A Microsoft também criou o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) que é diferente de tudo isto mas ela não investiu muito nele. Eu gostava da ideia, mas de fato ele acabou não fazendo tanto sentido para o mundo .NET.

Em maio de 2019 a Microsoft anuncia o [.NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Muitos não perceberam ou entenderam o que ele é, alguns se assustaram, mas aconteceu o que eu achei que iria acontecer. O .NET 5 (note que o nome não tem Framework ou Core no nome) na verdade é a próxima versão do .NET Core depois da que sai em 2019. Antes o nome .NET sozinho era usado como um nome informal, mas nenhum produto chamava só .NET. No segundo semestre de 2019 sai o .NET Core 3, a próxima deveria ser o .NET Core 4, certo? Mas a Microsoft resolveu pular esta versão porque o .NET Framework 4 ficou forte por muito tempo e é a versão atual. Então em 2020 sai o .NET Core 5. Mas ele não terá esse nome.

Como eu previra o modelo de atualização do .NET Framework era insustentável e criava problemas de *deploy* para as pessoas, entre outros problemas. Já há algum tempo ele não consegue evoluir mais como o .NET Core consegue. Ele sequer consegue evoluir para se manter dentro das novas versões do [.NET Standard](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113264/101). Inclusive alguns recursos do C# 7 não funciona nele, e do C# 8 piorou. Ele está perdendo muito em performance e segurança em relação ao .NET Core. Não faz mais sentido mantê-lo vivo.

Claro que a Microsoft não está o abandonando, ele faz parte do Windows, estará aí por anos ou décadas. Em março eu estive com o time do .NET, C#, etc. em Redmond e eles garantiram até extra oficialmente falando que o suporte ao .NET Framework continua sem problemas, ao mesmo tempo que disseram que ele não terá mais evolução. Portanto basicamente ele só receberá atualizações de segurança ou problemas muito graves e a Microsoft dará apoio para quem usa, ainda é um software ativo dela. Nesse ponto ele não morreu. Porém sem evoluir, morreu, não? Pra mim morreu, não me interessa algo que não evoluirá mais.

Pois bem, esse novo .NET Core 5 será a única implementação que continuará receber investimentos. A Microsoft não vai mais investir no Mono (que hoje ela é a dona dele, começou o desenvolvimento fora, mas ela comprou junto com a Xamarin, e fez acordo com a Unity para adotar o Core) e resolveu que o .NET Native não fazia mais sentido com o fim do seu celular. Note que o `runtime* do Mono ainda deve existir porque ele atende uma necessidade diferente. Mas não quer dizer que ele continuará usando compilador ou biblioteca próprios como era. Até o GC e JITter provavelmente usarão o que já existe do Core (não se sabe todos detalhes no momento que escrevo isto).

Claro ainda tem cenários que o Mono ou o .NET Native ainda são necessários, e essa nova versão do Core estará apta a fazer tudo o que só essas duas implementações fazem de forma exclusiva hoje (ainda que exija um *runtime mínimo diferente). Com toda essa capacidade em um único produto e não tendo evolução do .NET Framework, o Core passa ser a única implementação real completa e não precisa mais chamar Core para diferenciar das outras. Então em 2020 o .NET Core ganha uma nova versão e ela se chamará .NET 5.

[image: Diagrama de como o .NET 5 é composto]

O advento do .NET 5 enterra o .NET Framework que só deve ser usado para aplicações legadas, e isto se realmente não tiver um jeito fácil de passar para o Core.

Para quem não sabe, o .NET Core 3 já suporta alguns cenários que antes não funcionava nele, como o uso de WinForms, WPF, EF6, e outros. Os cenários que ele não suporta ainda, não será suportado porque é muito ruim e deveria ser abandonado em favor das soluções melhores que tem para o Core. E tem para todas que ainda podem ser úteis.

Pra mim o .NET Standard passa fazer pouco sentido e se torna legado, embora oficialmente não tenha um posicionamento sobre isto.

E podemos ver o *roadmap* usado até chegar no .NET 5 e versões futuras, que agora será lançado de forma mais previsível.

[image: Roadmap .NET 5 e adiante]

O futuro é o .NET Core, através do .NET 5 e **o .NET Framework morreu** pra aplicações novas (pelo menos para pessoas em sã consciência, quem foi teimoso no começo ganhou legados novos sem necessidade). Desta forma o .NET está mais forte do que nunca! Tem momento que uma morte é necessária pra se fortalecer. E continua com sua performance lendária (na verdade a versão nova está mais rápida ainda do que demonstrado aqui e deve assumir o primeiro lugar - os que estão na frente são experimentais e não rodam em projetos reais).

[image: Comparação de performance de diversos stacks de tecnologia dando destaque para o .NET Core]
[Fonte](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r17&hw=ph&test=plaintext). Eu queria por o Node que falam que é rápido, mas ele estava muito pra baixo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ótima resposta! Acredita que elementos já do .NET Framework como o Windows Forms pode evoluir com o novo .NET 5, como criar um ".NET Forms" que seja compatível com todas as plataformas?

Comment: Acho que haverá alguma evolução nas mãos da comunidade já que está tudo aberto agora https://github.com/dotnet/winforms, mas rodar em outras plataformas acho mais difícil, tem quem diga que fará, mas não é tão simples. Pode ser, mas não sei se o resultado será bom. De certa forma já tem um feito pro Mono e ficou bem ruim. Claro que agora pode ficar melhor.