# Como o Windows gerencia os frameworks de instalação?

Tags: .net, .net-core, instalador, .net-5

Hoje estava a perguntar me como funciona o gerenciamento dos *frameworks* no Windows.

Vai sair a nova versão [.NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/?fbclid=IwAR2dBjscvW-C2l1rVZyfd0YEVzXwf6WiTqgnjJOrQZfCrSneNpJztR9PcA4), isso significa que terei de instalar esta versão para instalar programas feitos com esta versão no Windows?

Por exemplo os programas feitos em [.NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/?fbclid=IwAR2dBjscvW-C2l1rVZyfd0YEVzXwf6WiTqgnjJOrQZfCrSneNpJztR9PcA4) para desktop quando os instalar terei de instalar também o [.NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/?fbclid=IwAR2dBjscvW-C2l1rVZyfd0YEVzXwf6WiTqgnjJOrQZfCrSneNpJztR9PcA4) ou isso vem nos updates do Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não, o .NET 5 não é instalável, assim como qualquer [.NET Core que no fundo é o .NET 5 em diante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101). Ele gera uma aplicação auto contida com tudo o que precisa e por isso basta copiar na máquina e executar direto. Chama e executa, simples assim.

Ele não vai fazer nada de especial como instalar algo antes. O .NET Core 3, ou .NET 5, tem tudo o que ele precisa nele mesmo de forma simples e não tem aquelas dificuldades que fizeram as pessoas adotarem a web para não ter que instalar algo (e passaram ter problemas muito piores).

Inclusive já está disponível (nem precisa esperar o .NET 5, já tem no .NET Core 3) a possibilidade de gerar um executável único com tudo o que precisa sem ter que se preocupar com dependências. Por isso não tem nada que gerenciar na máquina que vai executar. Sua única preocupação é em configurar o *deploy* quando tudo estiver pronto na sua máquina de desenvolvimento, mas isso é super fácil e feito com o CLI `dotnet` que está ajunto do .NET Core.

O .NET 5 não depende de algo instalado previamente e roda em qualquer sistema operacional suportado, mesmo não Windows. Então não tem que instalar nada, nem mesmo sua aplicação (precisa só estar disponível, dá pra executar até remotamente).

Não tem nada para atualizar, você tem um executável e é aquilo. A atualização pode ser feita da forma mais simples possível, copia o executável novo com a nova versão (ou chama ele remotamente). Pode ter um mecanismo mais sofisticado mas é problema seu desenvolver ou usar uma biblioteca que ajude, já tem algumas.

O .NET 5 (ou Core 3) nada tem a ver com o .NET Framework e não tem porque ele vir com o Windows, inclusive porque ele foi feito para rodar em outros sistemas operacionais também. Ele não funciona mais como o .NET Framework funcionava que estava no Windows e era dependência. O Windows não tem que ter nada ou fazer qualquer coisa para sua aplicação funcionar. Claro tem que ter o básico do sistema operacional, mas nada especial para ele. Repito, até porque ele roda em diversos outros sistemas operacionais. Mudou completamente a forma como ele funciona comparando com o que está acostumado com o .NET Framework.

Estou sendo repetitivo porque aparentemente não ficou claro que só tem um executável que você chama e executa na hora que precisa, e não tem mais nada.

Claro que se você pode criar um instalador e fazer algum tipo de instalação, mas não é necessário. Claro que se quiser pode mandar um monte de arquivos separados, mas não precisa, são coisas opcionais e que eu não vejo vantagem alguma. Um instalador poderia fazer algumas coisas extras antes de executar a primeira vez, mas dá para fazer o mesmo na primeira vez que o executável é chamado naquela máquina.

Comment: Do ponto de vista do utilizador, basta ele instalar a aplicação no windows e o programa irá correr? Ao instalar ele instala o .net 5 ou isso não tem nada haver?

Comment: Ele não precisa instalar, basta chamar o executável. Não precisa instalar nada, nem sua aplicação, nem nada, não há processo de instalação.

Comment: São então os updates do windows que mantém a compatibilidade das aplicações desenvolvidas para o desktop desenvolvidas sobre esta nova framework?

Comment: Não existem updates, não existe nada instalado, é tudo auto contido, não precisa de nada. Se você quiser atualizar algo você chama ou copia uma nova versão do executável e boa. Se quiser que seja automático faz algum mecanismo pra isso, existem bibliotecas que ajudam, mas só para quem quer algo mais sofisticado. Tudo que estou escrevendo aqui é repetição do que está na resposta, mas falarei de novo: Esquece o .NET Framework, não tem nada a ver com ele, mudou a forma de lidar com isso.