# Os novos executáveis auto-contidos do .NET são realmente nativos?

Tags: .net, .net-core, runtime, cross-platform, .net-5

[Nessa pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/412598/como-o-windows-gerencia-os-frameworks-de-instala%C3%A7%C3%A3o), foi discutido sobre se existe a necessidade de instalar o .NET 5 (ou o .NET Core 3) na máquina para rodar executáveis compilados, e a resposta é:

> Não, o .NET 5 não é instalável, assim como qualquer .NET Core que no fundo é o .NET 5. Ele gera uma aplicação auto contida com tudo o que precisa e por isso basta copiar na máquina e executar direto. Chama e executa, simples assim.
>
> <sup>*@Maniero na resposta aceita da pergunta supramencionada. Retirado 30/09/2019 às 11:00.*</sup>

A dúvida é: já que estes executáveis são *runtime-less*, ou seja, não necessitam de uma dependência externa na máquina para serem executados (como o .NET Framework), são estes executáveis nativos nas plataformas destinadas?

- Por exemplo, o `.exe` gerado é um executável de Win32? Existe um `MSIL/CIL` por trás do mesmo ou seu código é igual feito no C (gerado um `x86` direto à estrutura e arquitetura do `.exe`)?
- Se sim, como isso funciona? É uma transpilação ou compilação direta ao código de máquina?
- Estes executáveis dependem de um Just-in-time Compiler para execução ou posso rodar num cenário mínimo do Windows (como o Modo de segurança)?
- É o mesmo processo para as outras plataformas com arquiteturas diferentes?
- Não precisarei mais instalar o `dotnet` no Linux e rodar um executável com `dotnet .\meuExecutavel.dll`? <sub>(Exemplo)</sub>

Comment: Rodam em cima da plataforma DOTNET (Plataforma de desenvolvimento) e independente se são Core ou Full ...

Comment: Nesse link para download: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download, então, para rodar a versão mais recentes ou antigas, precisa sim ser instalado nas maquinas e o executavel ou dll criados precisam desse cara para funcionar ...

Comment: ah então precisa instalar alguma coisa pra rodar eles, ue

Comment: Sempre tem que instalar, ou o meta pacote, ou os pacote individuais (esses inclusive só para funcionar uma determinada app) nada é mágico... leitura: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Jun/05/Which-NET-Core-Runtime-Download-do-you-need na minha opinião é melhor instalar o meta pacote (sdk)  mesmo que seja só para rodar porque já tem tudo o que precisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, pelo menos na forma normal. Os arquivos que parecem executáveis não são completamente executáveis assim, eles possuem um *bytecode* e não um código pronto para ser executado. Ele é encapsulado no mesmo tipo de arquivo que um executável normal, mas ele só tem código que o .NET entende, que é multi plataforma e não para uma específica.

Isso não quer dizer que você não pode ter alguns arquivos na sua solução que não seja executável mesmo. Por exemplo se você usa e manda o SQLite junto com sua aplicação este executável é totalmente nativo e tem que ser para a plataforma específica que ele vai rodar.

Se for usar desta forma normal você sempre precisa de algo extra para executar esse arquivo por ele não ser exatamente um executável.

Mas está tudo evoluindo e agora no .NET Core 3 já é possível que tudo o que precisa fique em um executável, até mesmo esses arquivos que citei acima podem estar juntos, então você chama e ele sabe iniciar a execução e sabe que tem várias coisas dentro dele que serão usadas para a execução real, mas é só um nível extra de abstração.

Isso pode parecer estranho mas é como se esse arquivo executável tivesse outros arquivos dentro dele, executáveis ou não. Esse arquivo principal que você vê e copia é executável e é específico para a plataforma que vai rodar. Os arquivos que estão dentro não são (necessariamente) específicos (pode ter algum, como o do SQLite que eu citei), inclusive pode ter arquivos texto. Lá dentro pode ter o que hoje conhecemos como DLLs .NET e que nos acostumamos ver como executáveis, estas continuarão iguais nesta modalidade, elas executarão depois do processo de JITter.

Na verdade desde o Mono já existe uma solução e agora no .NET Core também tem que em vez de você usar o [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) para gerar o código nativo da plataforma em memória no momento que está executando é possível gerar o executável nativo e por isso específico para uma plataforma.

Com o .NET 5 isto será mais consolidado e terá ainda um novo modo que gera código 100% nativo, quase como se fosse feito em C++ para dar uma comparação.

Percebeu que agora tem várias formas de entregar sua aplicação?

> Por exemplo, o .exe gerado é um executável de Win32? Existe um MSIL/CIL por trás do mesmo ou seu código é igual feito no C (gerado um x86 direto à estrutura e arquitetura do .exe)?

Depende de qual modo está falando :) Se for essa nova forma auto contida ele será um `.exe` Win32, conhecido como formato PE ([algo próximo aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/403699/101)), na sua base pra começar rodar, ou se for no Linux usará formato ELF (Mach-O no Mac). Esse executável terá algo x86 pra gerenciar tudo isso, mas sua aplicação não será x86 direta, ainda funciona tudo do jeito de antes, apenas está tudo em uma coisa só.

Existirá uma forma que o executável será x86, por exemplo, igual C, conforme disse acima, mas é outra forma de entregar.

> Se sim, como isso funciona? É uma transpilação ou compilação direta ao código de máquina?

Hoje não tem isso, quando tiver gerará código de máquina direto. Um teste antigo usava o *backend* do compilador do C++ para fazer isto, mas não deve ser assim no .NET 5 (não estou garantindo).

> Estes executáveis dependem de um Just-in-time Compiler para execução ou posso rodar num cenário mínimo do Windows (como o Modo de segurança)?

Esse atual depende sim. Quando conseguir produzir o nativo mesmo não depende. Há até uma vantagem de ter o JITter porque agora ele pode fazer otimizações extras que o executável puro não pode, o JITter do .NET melhorou muito nisso, por isso anda batendo recordes de performance. Então ainda tem as mesmas limitações de antes. O que for nativo no futuro poderá rodar bem em qualquer lugar que aceite um executável qualquer.

Esse nativo que eu falo é um novo modo do .NET 5 e não o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) que está morto, para todos efeitos. Certamente é muito parecido, mas ele é melhor, o .NET Native tinha limitações importantes do que dava para fazer.

> É o mesmo processo para as outras plataformas com arquiteturas diferentes?

Se entendi, sim.

> Não precisarei mais instalar o dotnet no Linux e rodar um executável com dotnet .\meuExecutavel.dll? (Exemplo)

Não, isso já é possível, você pode ter tudo sem instalar nada, dá trabalho e muitas vezes não compensa. Antes tinha que copiar pelo menos um arquivo junto, agora no .NET Core 3 pode estar [tudo no mesmo arquivo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables) e simplifica mais ainda.

Note que na sua máquina de desenvolvimento você precisa de outras coisas, isto tudo vale para a máquina que vai executar.

[image: Single File Executable]

Comment: Esse processo é bem semelhante ao que o ILMerge já fazia à anos.

Comment: É mais que isso, inclusive porque antes você dependia do .NET instalado, agora não mais.