# O .NET tem um tipo de host ou serviço de gerenciamento?

Tags: .net

Vejo no Windows que quando executo uma aplicação, aparece somente um processo no gerenciador de tarefas. Porém os aplicativos não são assemblies nativos.

Em JAVA o `Host` é o JAVA em sí.

Há algum tipo de host responsável pelo JIT ou algum tipo de serviço?

Ele carrega as bibliotecas responsáveis pelo tempo de vida do aplicativo em memória?

Se por acaso eu executar 200 aplicativos ao mesmo tempo ele vai carregar esses assemblies 200 vezes na memória?

Como isso funciona na prática?

Qual o critério de engenharia/arquitetura em se fazer tamanho malabarismo computacional?

- É uma questão de segurança?
- Independência de plataforma?

Qual seria?

Comment: Quando você fala em "host" acredito que esteja falando de Runtime, certo? Se sim, o nome do runtime do .NET é [CLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr).

Comment: Também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/413345/101

Comment: Host é um termo genérico, hospedeiro, como o assembly não é nativo, algo tem que hospedar esse assembly e fazer ele funcionar, eu conheço a terminologia, mas queria compreender melhor o life-time de um aplicativo.

Comment: Nenhuma das respostas associadas responde minhas perguntas, mas é bem informativo.

Comment: Bem bacana isso. @Maniero você escreve livros também? Eu compraria um...

Comment: @Edney Sou outro à espera de um livro do Maniero =)

Comment: Btw, @Edney, se nenhuma resposta reponde de fato a sua pergunta. Você pode editá-la e tentar torná-la um pouco mais específica.

Comment: @Edney tenho vontade, mas dá muito trabalho e não dá dinheiro, então não arrumei tempo ainda. Não pode ser como resposta no SOpt que vc dá de qq jeito e tá bom, livro é mais sério, não pode errar :D

Comment: Eu editei um pouco, eu entendo esse processo, a linguagem intermediária, o JIT, as bibliotecas e tal, mas a minha pergunta seria mais sobre como isso especificamente ocorre na execução do aplicativo. O JITTER em sí é um aplicativo, ele é carregado pelo processo que eu executei, ou há um serviço específico que faz isso? (como um servidor de aplicação), mais por aí.

Comment: A pergunta é muito ampla, se fosse mais específica daria para formular uma resposta, genérica assim a resposta tem que ser genérica.https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/101

Comment: @LINQ vc já pode escrever um tb :D